# Confused with Array in Java

Tags: arrays, methods

1. Could someone please answer why the output of this code is 225? Why not 222 since you are changing a?
2. When you look at code no.2 a when a is passed to test(), it completely changed. My question is why is that 'a' in  number 1 did not change when passed to test() while 'a' in number 2 changed?
   I'm a beginner at Java.

**1.**

```
public class Array1
{    
    static void test(int[] a)
    {
        int[] b = new int[2];
        a = b;
        System.out.print(b.length);
        System.out.print(a.length);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {     
        int[] a = new int[5];   
        test(a);   
        System.out.print(a.length);
    }
}
```

**2.**

```
public class Array2
{
    static void test(int[] a) {
    int[] b = new int[2];
    for(int i =0; i< a.length; i++)
    {
       a[i]=1;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    int[] a = new int[5];
    test(a);    
    for(int i =0; i< a.length; i++)
    {          
        System.out.print(a[i]);      
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what happens step by step in case 1

main: `int[] a = new int[5];` : declares a ref variable in main pointing to a array of 5 ints
main: `test(a)`; : calls test with a reference to the original array
test: `static void test(int[] a) {` : declares a ref variable `a` to hold a ref to the caller array => `a` in test is **another** reference to the original array
test: `int[] b = new int[2];` : declares a ref variable in test to a new array of 2 ints
test: `a = b;` : makes the ref variable `a` in test point to the new array => the original array is unchanged as is the `a` variable in main

remaining of the output is now normal.

Now case 2:

main: `int[] a = new int[5];` : declares a ref variable in main pointing to a array of 5 ints
main: `test(a)`; : calls test with a reference to the original array
test: `static void test(int[] a) {` : declares a ref variable `a` to hold a ref to the caller array => `a` in test is another reference **to the original array**
test: `int[] b = new int[2];` : declares a ref variable in test to a new array of 2 ints
...
test: `a[i] = 1;` : as `a` is a reference to the original array, you are changing values in the original array.

output should now be clear.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code you are getting 225:

following are the reasons:

let address of a be - aa111

let address of b be - bb111

1) you are changing the address of a in the test method so in test method a address will become bb111.

2)but you are not returning the a to the main method it restores to the original address of a which is aa111.

3) you will get 222 if you return a from test method.

here is the code for that

```
    public class Array1
    {    
          static int[] test(int[] a)
          {
               int[] b = new int[2];
               a = b;
               System.out.print(b.length);
               System.out.print(a.length);
               return a;
          }
          public static void main(String[] args) 
          {     
               int[] a = new int[5];   
               a = test(a);   
               System.out.print(a.length);
          }
     }
```